# Переопределить абстрактный метод сортировки объектов класса с++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, сортировка, stl

Всех приветствую. Стоит задача "Переопределить абстрактный метод сортировки объектов класса". Для Дочернего Класса Student по Году Рождения, а для Worker по зарплате. Есть мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
class Human {
    public: 
        string LastName;
        string FirstName;
        string DoubleName;
        double YearBirth;
        string Sex; 
        Human(){
            LastName = "";
            FirstName = "";
            DoubleName = "";
            YearBirth = 0;
            Sex = "";
        }
        Human(string _LastName, string _FirstName, string _DoubleName, double _YearBirth, string _Sex)
        {
            LastName = _LastName;
            FirstName = _FirstName;
            DoubleName = _DoubleName;
            YearBirth =  _YearBirth;
            Sex = _Sex;
        }
        virtual void Show() const   = 0;    
        virtual void SortHuman(int CountHuman) = 0;
        virtual ~Human(){}
};
class Student: public Human 
{   
    protected:
        string NameUniverse;
        string Specialty;
        double StudyCourse; 
    public:
        Student(){
        }
        Student(string _LastName, string _FirstName, string _DoubleName, double _YearBirth, string _Sex, 
                string _NameUniverse, string _Specialty, double _StudyCourse):
                Human::Human(_LastName, _FirstName, _DoubleName, _YearBirth, _Sex),
                NameUniverse(_NameUniverse), Specialty(_Specialty), StudyCourse(_StudyCourse) {}
        double ChangeStudyCourse(double _StudyCourse)
        {
            return this->StudyCourse = _StudyCourse;
        }
        void Show() const override 
        {
            cout<<endl<<"Студент: "<<endl<<"Фамилия: "<<LastName<<endl<<"Имя: "<<FirstName<<endl;   
            cout<<"Отчество: "<<DoubleName<<endl<<"Год Рождения: "<<YearBirth<<endl<<"Пол: "<<Sex<<endl;
            cout<<"Университет: "<<NameUniverse<<endl<<"Специальность: "<<Specialty<<endl<<"Курс: "<<StudyCourse<<endl;
        }
        bool comp(Student* lhs, Student* rhs) 
        {
            return lhs->YearBirth < rhs->YearBirth;
        }
        void SortHuman(int CountHuman) override 
        {
            Student* student;
            sort(student, student + CountHuman, student->comp);                     
        }   
        ~Student() {}
};
class Worker: public Human 
{
    protected:
        string Post;
        string PlaceOfWork;
        float Wages;
    public:
        Worker(){}
        Worker(string _LastName, string _FirstName, string _DoubleName, double _YearBirth, string _Sex,
               string _Post, string _PlaceOfWork, float _Wages):
               Human::Human(_LastName, _FirstName, _DoubleName, _YearBirth, _Sex),  
               Post(_Post), PlaceOfWork(_PlaceOfWork), Wages(_Wages){}
        void Show() const override  
        {
            cout<<endl<<"Работник: "<<endl<<"Фамилия: "<<LastName<<endl<<"Имя: "<<FirstName<<endl;  
            cout<<"Отчество: "<<DoubleName<<endl<<"Год Рождения: "<<YearBirth<<endl<<"Пол: "<<Sex<<endl;
            cout<<"Место Работы: "<<PlaceOfWork<<endl<<"Должность: "<<Post<<endl<<"Зарплата: "<<Wages<<endl;
        }
        void SortHuman(int CountHuman) override 
        {
            //sort();       
        }
        comp(Worker* lhs, Worker* rhs) 
        {
            return lhs->Wages < rhs->Wages;
        }
        float ChangeWages(float Persent)
        {
            return this->Wages*(1-(Persent/100));
        }
        ~Worker() {}
};
```

И в файле

> predefined_ops.h

Вываливаются такие ошибки:

```
[Error] must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (Student::*)(Student*, Student*)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (Student::*)(Student*, Student*)>::_M_comp (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (Student::*)(Student*, Student*)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (Student::*)(Student*, Student*)>::_M_comp) (...)'

[Error] must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<bool (Student::*)(Student*, Student*)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<bool (Student::*)(Student*, Student*)>::_M_comp (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<bool (Student::*)(Student*, Student*)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<bool (Student::*)(Student*, Student*)>::_M_comp) (...)'

[Error] must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<bool (Student::*)(Student*, Student*)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<bool (Student::*)(Student*, Student*)>::_M_comp (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<bool (Student::*)(Student*, Student*)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<bool (Student::*)(Student*, Student*)>::_M_comp) (...)'
```

Буду благодарен любой помощи

Comment: В методе Student::SortHuman Вы отдаете функции sort неинициализированный указатель, да и еще передаете как компаратор функцию-член

Comment: Куда это у вас вдруг пропал тип возвращаемого значения в объявлении метода???

Answer (score 0):

Если считать, что `Student* student` - это массив

```
//class Student
static bool comp(Student lhs, Student rhs) 
{
        return lhs.YearBirth < rhs.YearBirth;
}
void SortHuman(int CountHuman) override 
{
        sort(this, this + CountHuman, Student::comp);                     
}


//class Worker
void SortHuman(int CountHuman) override 
{
    sort(this, this + CountHuman, Worker::comp);       
}
static bool comp(Worker lhs, Worker rhs) 
{
    return lhs.Wages < rhs.Wages;
}
```

Пример использования

```
Student* s = new Student[10];
s[1].SortHuman(5);
// сортирует первые пять студентов начиная со второго
```

Компаратор принимает объект, который содержится в массиве